# How to save input data form with javascript avoid security content policy -Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i'm newbie on developping chrome extension and i'm facing a problem.

I need to get user input data and store it in some ways. I tryed with local.storage and sync.storage but they should work only with same domain since i cannot get data while i'm trying to inject javascript by using script in **content.js** file. It works on same domain (i suppose that in this case, when i open tab of chrome extension, local.storage save data only for that "domain").

How can solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Add more details:
-I have to save input data from popup.html in some way
-In content.js i need this data (assigning to a variable) and inject the data into another domain web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/).

// popup.js

```js
function submit(data) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, data);
  });
}
```

// content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  // do sth
});
```